# Java's lack of template inheritance is causing major code duplication headaches in Android. Any solutions?

Tags: java, android, multiple-inheritance

This is Android specific.

I derive all of my Activities in Android from a custom class that provides a nice, clean place to put common code used by all layouts in the application, especially some common setContentView() override code that injects layouts into my layouts.  So here is what a typical hierarchy looks like:

```
MyActivity extends MyBaseClass -> MyBaseClass extends Activity -> Activity
```

For one of my apps, I needed Google Maps support.  So I tried to turn MyBaseClass into a template/generic so that I could do something like:

```
MyActivity extends MyBaseClass<MapActivity> -> MyBaseClass<T> extends T -> T
```

Which, of course, failed to compile because Java templates/generics are not nearly as useful as C++ templates as I discovered shortly after the attempt.  So I ended up creating a whole separate class as a temporary workaround:

```
MyActivity extends MyBaseMapClass -> MyBaseMapClass extends MapActivity -> MapActivity
```

And copied all the code from MyBaseClass into MyBaseMapClass.  The code is identical except for a few minor changes involving imports.  It works, but it is hardly a good solution.

I crossed my fingers that the above would be the end of the problem and I would never have to revisit it again.

Unfortunately, I'm starting to experiment with a fragment and activity mix with a much more complex base class and the problem of code duplication with the above is getting to be a serious issue.  Any time I make a change in one file, I have to remember to clone it to the other files and development is moving fast enough that I'm quickly getting out of sync.

Activity, MapActivity, FragmentActivity, ListActivity, PreferenceActivity, etc.  Do I need to make a separate derived class for each and every one of those that I wish to use?  I hope not and, for this reason, I've already limited my derivations to begin with (some of my activities don't have certain features as a result).  The problem is further exasperated by the fact I sometimes use two separate base classes (where some activities need to inflate even more views into the layout but not all activities need to do so):

```
MyActivity extends MyBaseClass -> MyBaseClass extends Activity -> Activity

MyActivity2 extends AnotherBaseClass -> AnotherBaseClass extends MyBaseClass -> MyBaseClass extends Activity -> Activity
```

If I want to use the code for AnotherBaseClass in Maps, I not only have to create MyBaseMapClass, but also AnotherBaseMapClass and copy the code.  I'm up to four classes at this point where two of the classes are a couple thousand lines of cloned code.  Replicated code bothers me because it makes maintenance and development that much harder to do.

Deriving Android classes introduces complexities such as findViewById() being a part of the Activity base class.  That's important because I'm not sure how I would write an interface or composite without running into the same problems I just described.

Anyone here encountered this issue and come up with a workable solution?

Comment: *"Which, of course, failed to compile"* => Have you tried with `MyBaseClass<T extends Activity>`?

Comment: That's why composition should be preferred over inheritance. Side note: are you really Paula Bean? The [Brillant Paula Bean](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The_Brillant_Paula_Bean.aspx)?

Comment: @assylias - The problem is the use of a reference to "Activity".  Yes, I'm pretty sure that is one of the variants I tried.  As I mention above, findViewById() is part of Activity among most of the other useful Android SDK calls.  I just converted to what you mentioned and I get a lot of errors of the nature of "The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type MyBaseClass<T>".

Comment: @JBNizet - That would be better except all activities have to derive from Activity (or one of its variants).  The OS figures out how to call the activity via the XML manifest and does a lot of initialization and setup behind the scenes before onCreate() gets called for each Activity.  If you have one, I'd love to see an example where you don't derive from Activity (MapActivity, ListActivity, etc) but uses composition and the application still works/doesn't crash.

Comment: You need to udnerstand that Java Generics are not 'templates' at all. It is *templates* that cause code duplication: Generics provides a way to completelty avoid it. But you do have to understand the type algebra, which templates don't have at all, which is why they just duplicate code instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just create a helper class with a static function like `styleActivity(Activity a)`? This seems to be the easier solution in that case than to use inheritance.

Comment: Passing 'this' might move the bulk of the logic into the helper class, but I'll still have to have several classes for each Activity variant because I ultimately still have to derive from them.  I suppose this would solve my main issue of code replication.  But I have a question - will passing the 'this' (Activity) reference around hurt performance?

Comment: It wouldn't hurt performance, its just a reference. Just keep the methods static, and any shared objects will have to be synchronized

Comment: So here's what I ended up doing:  I created a helper class of BaseClassHelper<T extends Activity> { private T act; public BaseClassHelper(T act) { this.act = act; } }  Then, from the main classes, I instantiated an object like:  private BaseClassHelper<MapActivity> bch = new BaseClassHelper<MapActivity>();  I still have some code duplication but the bulk is now in the helper class.  However, since I use SlidingMenu, it has its own problems in this vein.  When I want to call SlidingMenu methods, I have to attempt to cast the 'act' object to each Sliding...Activity type first.

Comment: I need to try using this first in another Activity type before accepting this answer.

Comment: This solution works well.  The helper class approach solves most of my code replication issues.  There are still a few minor problems, but I can deal with them.

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want multiple inheritance, which Java doesn't support.

Multiple inheritance can be simulated

```
interface MyBaseInterface
    foo();
    bar();

class MyBaseClass implements MyBaseInterface
    foo(){ ... };
    bar(){ ... };

class MyMapActivity extends MapActivity implements MyBaseInterface

    // boiler plate c&p
    MyBaseClass base;
    foo(){ return base.foo(); }
    bar(){ return base.bar(); }
```

However, what's the reason that MyMapActivity must `implements MyBaseInterface`? Probably none.

Maybe this is good enough

```
class MyBaseClass
    foo(){ ... };
    bar(){ ... };

class MyMapActivity extends MapActivity

    public final MyBaseClass base;
```

so everytime you need to treat `MyMapActivity` as `MyBaseClass`, just use the `base` variable.

```
    activity.base.foo();
```

for abstract/overriden methods

```
class MyMapActivity extends MapActivity

    public final MyBaseClass base = new MyBaseClass()
    {
        foo(){ do my foo thing; } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact your own statement "Java templates/generics are not nearly as useful as C++ templates" is the best answer to you question :).

Constructs like `class MyClass<T> extends T` are unfortunately illegal in java. And even if they were legal they would mean the same as `class MyClass extends Object` as parametrized types are erased in bytecode. (read about type erasure http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#What%20is%20type%20erasure?)

I would stick to Helper class suggested by SimonSays in another answer.

```
class MyHelper<T extends Activity> {

    final T activity;

    public MyHelper(T activity) {
        this.activity = activity;

        //here you can access Acitivities methods on T object 
        //and compiler will not say a single bad word ;)
        //unfotunately only public methods
        activity.getLayoutInflater();
    }

    public T getActivity() {
        return activity;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I ran into the public methods issue already.  Fortunately, Activity uses public methods for most things for the moment.  The methods that are 'protected' are things like onCreate(), which are usually chained together anyway (especially in libraries), so I wouldn't want to attempt to figure out how to call super.onCreate().  For those, I'm just calling the super method in the derived class.